# Rails Include Module on Condition

Tags: ruby, module, mongoid

I'm trying to include a module only when a condition is met.

```
module PremiumServer
  def is_premium
    true
  end
end

class Server
  include Mongoid::Document
  include PremiumServer if self.premium
  field :premium, :type => Boolean, :default => false
end
```

This isn't working, and I can't figure out why. Can someone please tell me how I'm supposed to include modules based upon a condition being met, like above?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I found the answer to my problem here: [Mongoid and carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6214384/mongoid-and-carrierwave)

However, I'm awarding the question to the top answer as it is probably the more useful way.

Comment: is premium a instance method or field? if so then this won't work, because include takes place at class level when it being loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

includes happen on the class level. Your premium attribute is at instance level.

There are ways to do the include on per instance level, but I would not recommend them.

Here you are better of using inheritance

```
class Server; .. ; end
class PremiumServer < Server; ..; end
```

Or, in your case, if the only method is `is_premium` add it to the Server class and have it return the premium variable

```
def is_premium
  self.premium
end
```

oh, and you should use "question" method in ruby... Although Mongoid provides these for boolean values.

```
def premium?
  self.premium
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use class inheritance and the scope mechanism of Mongoid:

```
class Server
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :premium, type: Boolean, default: false
  # ... basic server methods
end

class PremiumServer < Server
  default_scope :premium_servers, where(premium: true)
  # ... additional premium server methods
end

p_server = PremiumServer.first
p_server.<access to PremiumServer methods>
```

The `default_scope` will be used every time you do a query on `PremiumServer`, you do not need to call `.premium_servers` manually.

That is "conditional based" in another way - in a mongoid way.

Further information:

- Scopes: http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/scopes.html
- Inheritance: http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/inheritance.html